# NameError: name 'creds' is not defined

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I got an error,NameError: name 'creds' is not defined .I wanna use Google Cloud Vision API.I set up various things in Google Cloud and I downloaded google-cloud-sdk-180.0.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz ,and I run command `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init`,it was successful.I wrote test.py

```
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=creds,)

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'cat.jpg')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
```

and when I run this codes,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=creds,)
NameError: name 'creds' is not defined
```

the error happens.
I wrote codes by seeing https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/docs/vision/index.rst#id8 ,so I rewrote

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
```

error happens google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or
explicitly create credential and re-run the application. For more
information, please see
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials. . I really cannot understand why this error happens.I installed config.json & index.js & package.json in same directory as test.py but same error happens.I run command  `gcloud components update && gcloud components install beta` but zsh: command not found: gcloud error happens.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: it's right there in the error, you have not defined `creds`

Comment: @Phydeaux Oh really?So what should I define creds?Should I write it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this error you need to define the variable
Here is what I found on google cloud for the variable creds
Add this before client:

```
creds = mock.Mock(spec=credentials.Credentials)
```

and on the imports lines

```
from google.auth import credentials

import mock
```

Comment: thank you very much,I wrote ur codes ,so google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The request is missing a valid API key. error happens.I already got my API key and the result of my searching the error,I should defined 'key = myAPIKey' but I cannot understand  how I should use key variable.How should I do?

Comment: well this is one example of a key : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/test_utils/credentials.json.enc  so try reading from a  file or define the key by putting your api key in a string like this : key = 'a22b33bbbb3b3b3'

Comment: have you read the google cloud documentation? https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files